# Can rsync use a remote environment variable?

Tags: rsync, environment-variables

Say I want to use rsync to copy a remote folder to my local desktop:

```
rsync -av remote:$REMOTEDATA $LOCALDATA
```

But I want to access the $REMOTEDATA environment variable on the remote server, not the local desktop.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to get the environment from the remote machine into your local machine:

```
$> export $(ssh remote "env | grep REMOTEDATA) 
$> rsync -av remote:$REMOTEDATA $LOCALDATA
```

or something like that. the command (the fact that it is rsync does not really matter) is executed locally and your shell is replacing the $variables locally.

Comment: alright, that makes sense. thanks. So there is no way to do it within the `rsync` command so that I don't have to open `ssh` in addition?

Comment: nope. you dont know in advance what is set on the server.

Comment: Environment variables aren't set on computers, they're per-process things. I suspect the environment variable you're trying to get is set up by the shell initialization script(s) (/etc/profile or ~/.profile or something), so in order for the variable to even exist, you need to create a shell process on the remote computer, let the profile script create the variable, and then have the shell report the variable's value. (Which is what this answer does.)